# Magento 2.2.7 MAGENTO di:compile STOPS AT 1/7 PROCESS

Tags: magento2, amasty

I'm upgrading from Magento 2.1.7 to Magento 2.2.7 and PHP 7.1, When I run " php bin/magento setup:di:compile" it stops at 1/7 and
I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'Magento\SalesRule\Observer\SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver' not found in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/Amasty/Promo/Observer/FixCouponsUsageObserver.php on line 19

I'm using the following Amasty versions:
amasty/module-special-promo: "2.2.1",
amasty/promo: "1.4.0",
amasty/base: 1.4.10

As a result of this I'm getting the following error when checking out:

> code   500
>   message Fatal Error: 'Class 'Magento\SalesRule\Observer\SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver' not found' in '/home/mthabisi/projects/oliversweeney/vendor/amasty/promo/Observer/FixCouponsUsageObserver.php' on line 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have this type of error I follow those steps:

1 : Delete de var/di and var/generation folders and recompile.

2 : Check if the class "Magento\SalesRule\Observer\SalesOrderAfterPlaceObserver" Still exist. It could have been deleted or renamed in versions higher than 2.1.7

3 : If the class does not exist, update your plugin. The version of amasty you are using might only works with version prior to 2.2